# Creating and Styling a Contact Form?

Tags: html

Ok, So I am currently trying to create a contact form, and I understand how to create a basic one, to the brief that I have, however there is a specific way that I want the contact form to be styled and laid out, so I was just wondering if anyone could explain to me how I would style it like this, or if anyone could link me to a tutorial on how to do so.

http://gyazo.com/9a5de47a2f0a56ad637d30ba8e514059

I will also need it to be responsive.

Thank you

Comment: Sorry, but your question is too broad, and basically is asking us to do what people get paid for. You should try and style the form yourself, and if you get stuck come back with a specific problem.

Comment: I guess what I said didn't come out as I wanted it to, I just want to know how forms are styled, I don't want it to be done for me.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty new to this stuff myself. With styling being the main consideration here, the possibilities and combinations are endless.

I would consider making a few divs within the main contact form wrapper. Kind of try and keep the contact form whole. You may want to use a div for the first 3 text inputs on the left, the textarea input "message" as another one and lastly the submit button "contact". With that all in mind, the styling should be nothing more than adding some margin and padding between inputs and giving the proper width/height through specificity in CSS. Maybe give each div it's own id or class to distinguish specific input fields. Border radius can give that nice rounded edge on the input areas. Something like 8-10% is usually enough. Use some text align to get the input "value" (CONTACT) to center.

The responsiveness portion of your form would very much depend on how you want it laid out on another devices or resolutions. If you wanted them to stack on top of one another for smartphones and such; I believe you could do that with the display: inline and they should wrap appropriately with your breaks.

Here's a link you might be able to use for that. Hope this helps at all. Like I said, I'm new :).

https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/layouts/rwd-fundamentals/set-the-viewport?hl=en